# Why are files restored after JUnit test exits?

Tags: java, groovy, junit

I've written some unit tests in Groovy which is built on JUnit (I think 3.8.x) and I've noticed that files modified by tests are restored after the test exits. They seem to be rewritten after the `tearDown()` method is called and are restored back to the state that they were in after `setUp()`. Has anyone else seen this behavior? Can it be disabled?

Comment: What kind of files?  Can you show us a test case?  If you mean XML files and you don't explicitly save, all of the manipulation can be done in memory.

Comment: It is very hard to answer this question without the below details

1. What kind of files are you talking about.
2. Are these application specific or Groovy specific?

Starting 4.7, JUNIT introduced rules and one of them is TemporaryFolder: Allows test to create files and folders that are guaranteed to be deleted after the test is run. This is a common need for tests that work with the filesystem and want to run in isolation.

Comment: They are application specific text files

Comment: Are they integration tests? Sounds like they are getting rolled back with the transaction for some reason... have you tried static transactional = false to see what happens?

Comment: They are. Good thought - it didn't work though. I discovered an inherited test*() method which was causing setUp() to be called again and the files to be rewritten. Guess there was no hope of you guys figuring that out. Thanks anyway!

Comment: @balor123: If you have found the solution, please answer your own question and accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JUnit creates a new instance of the Test for every method, causing setUp() and tearDown() to be called multiple times.